# How to select all XML nodes that have a given child in Python 3?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have the following XML from nmap:

```
<nmaprun>
    <host>
        <address>
        <hostsnames>
        <ports>
        <hostscript>
    </host>
    <host>
        <address>
        <hostsnames>
        <ports>
    </host>
    <host>
        <address>
        <hostsnames>
        <ports>
        <hostscript>
    </host>
</nmaprun>
```

I only want to get the `host` elements that have the child `hostscript`. I followed the Python 3 [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example) with `root.findall(".//hostscript/..[@name='host']")`. In the example above, I should get only 2 out of 3.

Comment: `/nmaprun/host[hostscript]`?

Comment: Your attempt fails because `@name` assumes there is an attribute `name` that contains the exact text `host`. This does not occur anywhere in your sample XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the host elements that have the child hostscript, you can use this XPath:

```
/nmaprun/host[hostscript]
```

As others pointed out in the comments to your question, `@name` is looking for an attribute node. You likely wanted to use [`name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-name) instead.

Comment: Fixed the typo and thanks, actually, in my case just `./host[hostscript]` worked!